# Como validar data inicial e data final para um mesmo atributo do Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Descrição do problema:

Preciso criar um form com uma data inicial e data final para listar as vendas de um produto por período.

Tenhamos como exemplo este model:

```
public class Produto
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int IdProduto { get; set; }

    [Display(Name= "Descrição")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name= "Data Venda")]
    public string DataVenda { get; set; }
}
```

No form, teremos somente um campo de texto com a `datainicial`, outro com a `datafinal`, e o botão `submit`.

A minha dúvida é a seguinte: Neste caso, como eu faria para fazer as validações no formulário dos campos `datainicial` e `datafinal`, na VIEW, usando `Html.BeginForm`, tendo em vista que os campos `datainicial` e `datafinal` são o mesmo atributo no Model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em alguns casos a sua classe de domínio/modelo do banco de dados é facilmente adaptável à *view*, em outros casos não.

Recomenda-se que se crie modelos de visão para cuidar de casos específicos.
Por exemplo, quando você cria uma nova aplicação web com o template que contém o *"Individual User Account"* você terá uma classe *`LoginViewModel`* para a tela de Login, outra classe *`RegisterViewModel`* para a tela de registro, etc. Tudo dentro do arquivo *AccountViewModels.cs* na pasta *Model* do template do *Asp.Net MVC*.

Logo, digo, e é recomendado, que você crie um modelo padrão para cada view.

Então, você teria algo como:

```cs
public class ProdutoVendasPorPeriodoViewModel // nome nada exagerado
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informa a data inicial")]
    [Display(Name= "Data Inicial")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataInicial { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informa a data final")]
    [Display(Name= "Data Final")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Final { get; set; }
}
```

E em sua *view*, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```razor
@model App.Web.Model.ProdutoVendasPorPeriodoViewModel
...
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DataInicial)
....
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DataFinal)
```

Seguindo esse padrão, você teria vantagens como:

1. não precisar criar gambiarras para *views* que não representam o mesmo modelo da classe de domínio;
2. Também não teria os atributos *`DisplayAttribute`* "sujando" sua
   classe de domínio;
3. Poderá ter classes bem customizadas com atributos que lhe ajudariam na validação e modelagem da view, como o exemplo que dei, exigindo os valores de Data Inicial e Data Final com o atributo `RequiredAttribute` e o `DisplayAttribute` que passou a ter um valor mais "apropriado" para a *view*.

---

## Meios paliativos

Você pode ainda criar uma *view* não "tipada", ou seja, sem informar o `@model`.
Os campos você poderia criar manualmente ou com o uso de helpers também.

Exemplo:

```html
<input type="text" id="DataInicial" name="DataInicial" .. />
...
<input type="text" id="DataInicial" name="DataInicial" .. />

... ou

@Html.TextBox("DataInicial", "")
@Html.TextBox("DataFinal", "")
```

Para isso sua Action deveria ser assinada como esse exemplo:

```cs
public ActionResult Relatorio (string DataInicial, string DataFinal)
{
    ...
}
```

Ou seja, tendo os parâmetros com o nome dos campos.
Dessa forma você receberia os valores nos parâmetros e a validação ficaria por sua conta.

Comment: Eu posso estar utilizando em alguns casos o próprio model e para outros o viewmodel? Ou é recomendável que eu sempre use o viewmodel?

Comment: Estou no meio de um projeto no qual não conta com o ViewModel. Então utilizo DisplayAttribute por exemplo, direto no domínio. Porém agora para uma classe iria precisar utilizar viewmodel, e seria um retrabalho estar alterando tudo que já fiz para viewmodels.

Comment: Obrigado @TiagoSilva. A minha dúvida era justamente se era comum criar várias classes além da Model do Produto. Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Eu estava já iniciando o "Meio Paliativo" que você falou na resposta acima. Mas acho que vou aproveitar que ainda estou no início do projeto e fazer da forma correta mesmo.